# Connecting docker locally with vagrant provisioned docker

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to get docker running under vagrant but without using the full vagrant solution - I only want to use vagrant to create the vm and install docker on it which this does but I guess I've got to do some more stuff to the environment.

I'm running under this environment

```
Windows 8
Vagrant 1.7.4
Virtualbox 5.0.6
Cisco Anyconnect - I've read this can cause issues
```

Here's my vagrant script

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.hostname = "docker-host"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 2375, host: 2375

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.name = "docker-host"
    vb.memory = "4096"
    vb.cpus = 2
  end

  config.vm.provision "docker"
end
```

Running `vagrant up` works nicely and when I ssh in I can run `docker` and everything seems fine - or at least docker prints out.

Back on my local machine I've got a docker file and then I try to run `docker build .` which fails and I get the following output

```
An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://localhost:2375/v1.21/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=dockerfile&memory=0&memswap=0&rm=1&t=&ulimits=null: net/http: 
transport closed before response was received
```

If I try a `docker run --name some-redis -d redis` for instance I get the following error

```
An error occurred trying to connect: Post http://localhost:2375/v1.21/containers/create?name=some-redis: WSARecv tcp 127.0.0.1:50949: 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I'm wondering if anyone can help tell me what's the problem here and how I get get my local install of docker talking to my provisioned VM under vitualbox and vagrant.

I've tried `telnet localhost 2375` which seems to work ok